# Should I upgrade the bios on my eee-pc 1000h?

Tags: bios, eee-pc

I bought the eee-pc in 2008 and have never upgraded the bios. What benefit do I gain from upgrading the bios?

The [asus support](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Eee%20PC%201000H/XP&p=20&s=1) website lists 7 bios updates since 2008. Do I have to install them in chronological order or just the last one?

Answer (score 2):

BIOS upgrades generally add new features to motherboards; such as support for newer processors (not relevant in your case), they may fix reported operating bugs or might improve compatibility with an add-on.

The general rule is that you probably don't need to upgrade your BIOS unless you are experiencing a problem that is known to be fixed by doing so. You should be able to find out what's been changed or added by reading the BIOS update release notes or change logs.

Comment: +1, Agree, don't do it unless you have a problem that cannot be solved any other way.

Comment: What do I do if a changelog is unavailable? Asus hasn't provided any information. Is there a reliable website that gives out information on various bios upgrades and their updates?